# SonarQube Reverse Proxy Configuration

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I cannot get https working though the reverse proxy. Going from https to http seems to provide difficulty. Here are the configurations.

```
    ProxyPass               /sonar2 http://server:8998
    ProxyPassReverse        /sonar2 http://server:8998/sonar2

   <Proxy http://server:8998/*>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
      ErrorDocument 503 /error/sonar/503/index.html
    </Proxy>
    <Location /sonar>
      ErrorDocument 503 /error/sonar/503/index.html
    </Location>
```

Answer (score 2):

First it seems that your proxy configuration is incorrect, you should have :

```
ProxyPass               /sonar2 http://server:8998/sonar2
ProxyPassReverse        /sonar2 http://server:8998/sonar2
```

To help you further, can you describe your error ?

Did you configure the context of SonarQube to /sonar2 ?
Is SonarQube configured to listen on 8998 port ?